# Permission Request for account <name>@gmail.com

Tags: permissions

Starting tonight, I started getting notifications that read "Permission requested for account @gmail.com". When I click and hold to go to App Info, it disappears and nothing comes up. When I click on it, it reads:

> These apps want access to your Google account from now on:
>
> - com.lge.hiddenmenu
> - LGInstallService
> - Widevine Keybox Test
> - LGSetupWizard
> - LG MLT
> - PC Suite Service
> - Settings
> - com.lge.lockscreen
> - SystemBackupService
> - com.android.providers.settings
> - Google Backup Transport
> - LGSystemServer
> - Task Manager
> - Android System
> - Font Server
> - Key Chain
> - Input Devices
> - Aspect ratio correction
> - Camera Test
> - Shutdown Monitor
> - Home selector
> - com.lge.internal
> - LGATCMD Service
> - Wise Screen
>
> They are requesting permission to:
> Android Services

I click on No Thanks, and it comes back an hour later. I don't want to allow access, because I have no idea who is requesting it.

**How can I get rid of this forever, without giving access to those services that I don't use? Or is it actually required somehow?**

It's an LG Optimus G phone, rooted with stock ROM.